# phpMyAdmin - Error during session start;

Tags: phpmyadmin, localhost, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting the following error when I try to open PhpMyAdmin.

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13)

Initially PhpMyAdmin was working fine, the problem appeared after executing the following commands:
`chmod -R a+X /opt/lampp`
`chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the owner permissions, you probably changed the write permissions as root and it changed the owner permissions.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/lampp
```